# Children widgets in a row are placed vertically

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make the children widgets to be placed horizontally instead of vertically.

tried to swap widgets around still no luck.

Simplified Code:

```
  return MaterialApp(
        home: Container(
            child: Scaffold(
               body: ListView.builder(
                    // physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(), // new
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: 7,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      String date = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
                          .format(DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: index)));
                      return appointmentsOfSingleDayCopied(date);
                    }))));
```

appointmentsOfSingleDayCopied():

```
  Widget appointmentsOfSingleDayCopied(String date) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: appointmentsList,
      builder: (context, appointmentsFutureList) {
        if (appointmentsFutureList.connectionState == ConnectionState.none ||
            appointmentsFutureList.data == null) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
        List<Appointment> appointmentslist = appointmentsFutureList.data;
        return Column(children: <Widget>[
          Text("Date : $date",
              style: CustomTextStyle.previewCaseSmallFont(context)),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), // new
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: times9to2.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      Color backgroundColor = Colors.white;
                      if (appointmentslist
                          .where((item) =>
                              item.time == times9to2[index] &&
                              item.date == date)
                          .isNotEmpty) {
                        backgroundColor = Colors.red;
                        print("changing colors");
                      }

                      return Container(
                          child: Text(times9to2[index].substring(0,4),
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(backgroundColor: backgroundColor)),
                          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                            border: new Border.all(
                                color: Colors.blueGrey,
                                width: 5.0,
                                style: BorderStyle.solid
                            ),
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          ));
                    }),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ]);
      },
    );
  }
```

[image]

Times ( 9AM to 2PM) should be next to each other.

help much appreciated

Comment: in your `ListView.builder` add `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal`

Comment: @LonelyWolf thanks that worked